# when using solvePnP function in OPENCV 3.0

Tags: opencv3.0

what i wanna do is to get 4 vertice pixel points(2D coordinate) of QR-code,

and input both them and World-3D-coordination of QR-code as parameter of function, solvePnP.

but when i compile, solvePnP doesn't work! the error occurred something like this..

***Assertion failed (npoints >= 0 && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_32F), ipoints,checkVector(2, CV_64F))) in cv::solvePnP***

in solvePnP, it declared that it can use std::Vector type, or cv::Mat type, so i tried to change both of those date types. but it still can't..

my source code is below,

```
***Point3d pt[4];
pt[0] = Point3d(0, 0, 0);
pt[1] = Point3d(0, 178, 0);
pt[2] = Point3d(178, 178, 0);
pt[3] = Point3d(178, 0, 0);
vector<Point3f> objectPoints;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    objectPoints.push_back(pt[i]);  // 3d world coordinates
Point2d point[4];***
```

and after this procedure, i got the 4 vertices coordinates into point[] from QR code. and next is,

```
vector<Point2f> imagePoints;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        imagePoints.push_back(point[i]);    // 2d image coordinates


    //Mat objPts(4, 1, CV_64F, pt);
    //Mat imgPts(4, 1, CV_64F, point);

    // camera parameters
    double Intrinsic[] = { fx, 0, cx, 0, fy, cy, 0, 0, 1 };
    Mat Camera_Matrix(3, 3, CV_64FC1, Intrinsic);

    double Distort[] = { k1, k2, p1, p2 };
    Mat DistortCoeffs(4, 1, CV_64FC1, Distort);

    // estimate camera pose
    Mat rvec, tvec; // rotation & translation vectors

    solvePnP(objectPoints, imagePoints, Camera_Matrix, DistortCoeffs, rvec, tvec);
```

please help!

Answer (score 4):

In your code, the array "point/pt" is of Point2d, but "objectPoints/imagePoints" is a vector of Point2f.

By the way, different to the documentation, it seems that the solvePnP function requires the object points and image points to be in the format of vector or cv::Mat(N*2/3). I tried using cv::Mat(2/3*N) as input, but the same error of assertion failure appears.

You may follow the official example to help debug. It locates in /samples/cpp/tutorial_code/calib3d/real_time_pose_estimation/src.